# Re-formation of Fibonacci sequence formula

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I was doing some question on Fibonacci Sequence and came across this formula
$$\large F_n = \frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n - \left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n}{\sqrt5}$$
I started thinking “Is there a better way to write this formula? Because this seems ugly, look at the denominator, it has surd and the numerator is also not good for easy calculation”
So I did some calculations and reformed it in another way
$$
\large F_n^2 = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \dfrac{\left\lfloor \left(\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n \right\rfloor-1}        {5}; \;\text{n is even}\\\\
        \dfrac{\left\lfloor \left(\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n \right\rfloor+3}{5} ; \;\text{n is odd}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
How can we further simplify it? I want to cancel $5$ in the denominator and need to prove that these two expressions are perfect squares

Comment: I think for Fibonacci numbers greater than 10, you only need the first term in the numerator, keep the same denominator, then take the floor.

Comment: I don't know that that's actually a simplification.

Comment: Note that $\left|\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right|<1$ and $\sqrt{5}>2$, so $\left|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\right|<\dfrac{1}{2}$ for $n\ge 0$, and therefore $F_n$ is the closest integer to $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$.